# Can I host an application developed in ms visual studio 2003 on ms windows server 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2003

I have developed an application using Visual Studio 2003. I have been told the hosting environment will be of a Windows Server 2008. Does it support my application?

Comment: PLEASE DO NOT USE ALL CAPS. IT LOOKS LIKE YOU'RE SHOUTING.

Answer (score 1):

You need to consult the hosting service provider for clarification.

If you own the server yourself, you can feel free to install .NET Framework 1.1 and configure it,

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/472/how-to-install-aspnet-11-with-iis7-on-vista-and-windows-2008/

Comment: But we have no idea if this is a .NET app or not.

Answer (score 1):

You will definitely need to **test** your application on the target platform. Without testing, you won't know for sure.